# Dry wall damaged

Tags: drywall

I have removed stickers from the drywall in my kids room. The stickers didn't come off clean.

What's a good way to restore this? I am planning to paint a chalk board over this.

Should I use some thing like joint compound before painting over the chalkboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skim coating with drywall finishing compound and light sanding before primer then paint is the normal process for repairing the drywall surface that has minor surface damage.

I would highly discourage you from trying to paint the chalk board directly onto the drywall surface. Drywall surfaces, especially ones that have been patched up, are just not suitable for the chalk board type application. You should instead look to installing a purpose made chalk board onto the wall or create your own out of suitable materials. If you make your own, look at using a piece of sheet goods material that has a nice smooth surface on it. One such material would be a [Hardboard Tempered Panel](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hardboard-Tempered-Panel-Common-3-16-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-Actual-0-155-in-x-47-7-in-x-95-7-in-832780/202404545).